# How to set initial position of draggable points in JSXGraph in an equation graph?

Tags: javascript, math, jsxgraph, math.js

I'm developing a web software that plots an interactive polynomial equation with 2 variables on JSXGraph, I need that every point where the derivative of the equation is 0 to have a draggable point, and that when I drag one point, only the interval between 1 point after and 1 before the dragged point of the curve goes together does anyone knows how I could do that?

Comment: Can you post a sample equation?

Comment: Should the degree of the polynomial stay constant? This sounds like Lagrange interpolation or some sort of spline interpolation.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking too long to answer, I was with some personal problems, now I'm back.
One example of equation: y = -0.0037*x^5 + 0.071*x^4 + -0.35*x^3 + -0.23*x^2 + 2.8*x + 5.6 and no, the degree of the polynomial doesn't need to stay constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I guess, what you need is *Hermite interpolation*. I gave an example recently in Google groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsxgraph/OHls2NTOmUA). Hermite interpolation is not yet integrated in JSXGraph, but there seem to be a demand for it, so we may think about it.

Here is the code:

```
JXG.Math.Numerics.hermitePolynomial = function (p, derivatives) {
        var w = [],
            Lii = [],

            /** @ignore */
            fct = function (x, suspendedUpdate) {
                var i, k, xi, s,
                    L, Hi, Hi_hat,
                    len = p.length,
                    num = 0,
                    denom = 0;

                if (!suspendedUpdate) {
                    // Compute denominator
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        w[i] = 1.0;
                        Lii[i] = 0.0;
                        xi = p[i].X();

                        for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                            if (k !== i) {
                                w[i] *= (xi - p[k].X());
                                Lii[i] += 1 / (xi - p[k].X());
                            }
                        }

                        w[i] = 1 / w[i];
                    }
                }

                s = 0.0;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    xi = p[i].X();
                    L = w[i];
                    for (k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                        if (k !== i) {
                            L *= (x - p[k].X());
                        }
                    }

                    Hi = (1.0 - 2 * (x - xi) * Lii[i]) * L * L;
                    Hi_hat = (x -xi) * L * L;
                    s += p[i].Y() * Hi + derivatives[i] * Hi_hat;
                }
                return s;
            };

        return fct;
    };

var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard("jxgbox", {
            boundingbox: [-5, 6, 6, -5],
            axis: true
});

var p = [];
// Define the points
p[0] = board.create('point', [-1,2], {size:4});
p[1] = board.create('point', [1,-2], {size:4});
p[2] = board.create('point', [3,-1], {size:4});

// The derivates at this points are all zero.
var derivatives = [0, 0, 0];

var f = JXG.Math.Numerics.hermitePolynomial(p, derivatives);
var graph = board.create('functiongraph', [f, -10, 10], {strokeWidth:2});
```

A live demo is at https://jsfiddle.net/vcL7aepo/278/

Best wishes,
Alfred

Comment: Could you please explain how this code works? Because I pass the equation I want to plot as a parameter from other js file. Here's my project https://github.com/tatisstiv/equation_plotter_and_editor I would like to use your code to substitute equationchart.js

Comment: Now I begin to understand. You want a) to hand over an equation of the form `y = polynomial(x)`. b) Then, the extremal values inside of a certain interval have to be found. c) At these extremal coordinates, JSXGraph points are created. d) When dragging these points, the curve should adapt, but keep the extremal points at the JSXGraph points.